# php while loop with row variable

Tags: php, loops

Not sure why this will not work?  Does the loop not like my variable?  If I hard code this workings...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultno))
  {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><a href=reportip.php?prov=&date1=$date1&starthour=$hour1&endhour=$hour2&prov=$prov&date2=$date2&$hour2&$prov=13&lookup=" . $row['$radio'] . ">" . $row['$radio'] . "</a></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['count'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
```

Comment: We need to see more code - how are you getting $resultno? Also, are you sure the query is returning any rows? If there aren't any rows returned, your loop will have nothing to loop through :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'$radio'` is a string, not a variable. Remove the apostrophes and make it into `$radio`:

```
$row[$radio]
```

This will make it possible to choose a column from the MySQL resultset by setting $radio to the chosen value.

Answer (score 0):

Your row is not likely to have a `$radio` key; maybe you meant `$row['radio']`. Or `$row[$radio]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your array referencing is wrong:

```
$row['$radio']
```

should be written as follows, when referencing an array element using another variable

```
$row[$radio]
```

or as follows when accessing an element name

```
$row['radio']
```

Answer (score 0):

`$row['$radio']` seems to be a problem. Is `$radio` a variable with a value you would like to use as index for the `$row` then write `$row[$radio]` otherwise if the table column is named "radio" only write `$row['radio']`.